# Compare _TCHAR* argv[] entries from command line to _T("paramString")

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I know how to get the parameters from the command line.  I also know how to print them out.

The problem I'm having is how to compare the parameters from the argv[] array to a string.  The progam runs but never returns a result where the parameter string is equal to the one I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

```
// Testing.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i = i + 1)
    {       
    if (argv[i] == _T("find"))
    {
        wcout << "found at position " << i << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        wcout << "not found at " << i << endl;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers say, `strcmp()` or `wsccmp()` depending on whether you are compiling with UNICODE defined, which `_tcscmp()` from  will do for you.

Comment: NO! look at @fseydel answer: `_tccmp()` only compares the first char or each given pointer.

Comment: @Seki: Thanks! I updated to the correct macro since I somehow got accepted (3 years ago!). `_tccmp()` isn't even properly documented, so I might have just typo'd it, but it's scary it has the same signature.

Comment: it was just to help someone that would find this answer like I did yesterday and would after wonder why the string comparison is so weird... :^)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use strcmp function for the compare.
what you're doing write now is just comparing the pointers.
please note that strcmp returns 0 if the strings are equal.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i = i + 1)
    {       
    if (_tcscmp(argv[i], _T("find")==0)
    {
        wcout << "found at position " << i << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        wcout << "not found at " << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simon wrote:

> which _tccmp() from will do for you

This is actually wrong. 
`_tccmp()` compares chars (so it would only compare the 'f' in "find").

It's `_tcscmp()` doing the job!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (argv[i] == _T("find"))
```

This will only the compare the pointers `argv[i]` and pointer pointed to `"find".` What you need is to compare the strings. you can use [`strcmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731%28VS.80%29.aspx), ( `wcscmp`, for unicode)

```
  0 == wcscmp( argv[i], _T("find"))
```